# How to embed a bokeh js plot in a web page with CSP?

Tags: javascript, bokeh, nonce

The `div` generated by bokeh uses inline `style`, giving the error `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-...'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution`.

Comment: I don't think that is coming from a style tag. Are you using Bokeh 1.x? Bokeh only added SRE hashes to scripts in version 2.0 (You'll need to use CDN resources as well to get the hashes). In general more information is needed, there's not enough here to speculate beyond that.

Comment: it's version 2.1.1

Comment: Is this a Bokeh server app? Standalone content?

Comment: It's a static plot

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions to offer given only this. If you can provide a complete minimal code and instructions to reproduce, it would be reasonable to open an issue.